# Need both "www" and without www to work on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

This is a WordPress site.

Originally the person who built the site had set it up so that the site gets pulled up by going to `domain.com`. So all requests for `www.domain.com` gets punted to `domain.com`.

This is the standard code inside my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How can I change my .htaccess file so that this forward does NOT happen and folks can get to the site using BOTH `domain.com` as well as `www.domain.com`...??

Comment: They can already. If you serve the same content on `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`, then your site gets penalized by search engines. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Actually they cannot. Like I mentioned in my OP, if they type in `www.domain.com` they get redirected to `domain.com`. I want both of these to work without the redirection.

Comment: So you don't care about Search Engines penalization for duplicite content? In this .htaccess there is nothing about redirecting to domain.com.

Comment: Yes, that is correct about not worrying about search engines penalizing me for duplicate content. I know nothing about coding so the redirection is probably a part of WordPress itself.

Comment: Regarding the comments above: “Duplicate content” is mostly an issue with two completely different domains … when it is just about www vs non-www version of the same site, search engines are mostly smart enough to recognize that and not take it too seriously. Besides, there are other measures to fight it besides automatically redirecting (f.e. specifying canonical URLs).

Comment: I am more or less assuming you'll have to put a hacky solution in wp-config.php magically changing that variable based on the current domain name. http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Actually, after testing a bit it doesn't seem that wordpress redirects by itself. Changing the links according to the document in my previous comment will only affect links in your wordpress itself. My best guess is that it also redirects if you temporarily disable wordpress, and that it is either defined somewhere in your .htaccess or in the main config file you may or may not have access to.

Comment: Looks like WordPress itself determines which version will show up. The `WordPress Address` field in Settings is what sets the tone. There is no easy way to make both non-www and www work. Can be done via .htaccess I suppose but definitely not worth the effort. Sumurai8, if you create a separate answer I will award this to you as you did point me in the right direction when you provided the link above. Nonetheless, thank you ALL for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like WordPress itself determines which version will show up. The WordPress Address field in Settings is what sets the tone. There is no easy way to make both non-www and www work. Can be done via .htaccess I suppose but definitely not worth the effort.